# How to Add One SPFx Webpart into Other SPFx Webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

I have many SPFx webparts. All are developed either by "React" or "No Javascript" concepts. Now, I want to merge all webparts into SPFx React single page application.

Is there any way using we can add webpart zone in SPFx React and then add webpart to that zone?

In short, I need nested webparts using SPFx.

Kindly advise here.

Thanks in advance!